# SSRS 2008-R2 Add an image without taking up the whole tablix field

Tags: image, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I have an image that need to go in the same tablix field as some text but it just takes up the whole field. The image below shows what I am trying to achieve, I need for that image to be smaller and the text to be in the same field.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Answer (score 1):

One method is to put a **Rectangle** report item in your Tablix cell. You can then put both text boxes and images in the rectangle, and move and resize them as necessary. (A `List` report item is essentially the same as a rectangle in a single-cell table.)

Alternatively, setting the borders between the image and text cells to `None` might give you the effect you need. If you use this method and want to resize your image to be smaller than the cell, you may need to save the image file as the desired size, then set the Sizing property of the image report item to `Clip` or `AutoSize`.

Comment: Try changing the border property of your rectangle